# Markov Chain problem with first passage time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $X$ a Markov Chain with space state $S$, and transition matrix $P$. Let $A \subset S$ and $\tau_A = \inf\{n \ge 0: X_n \in A\}$ . Suppose that exists $n \ge 1$ and $\alpha > 0$ that for all $x \in A^c$ (the complement of $A$), $p^n_{x,A} \ge \alpha$. i) Show that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in S$, $\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A > kn) \le (1 - \alpha)^k$. ii) Show that $\mathbb{E}_x[\tau_A] \le \frac{n}{\alpha}$, and in particular, $\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A < \infty) = 1$.

This is how I tried to solve it:

If $x \in A$, we have
$$\mathbb P _x(\tau_A = 0) = 1 \implies \mathbb P _x(\tau_A > kn) = 0 \le (1-\alpha)^k.$$

Let $x \in A^c$. If $\lambda = (\lambda_i : i \in S)$ is a probability distribution of $X$, so $\lambda_x = \mathbb P_x(X_0 = x)$. Moreover, it's known that

1. By definition of $\lambda$, we have $\lambda_x \le 1$;
2. Since $X$ is Markov Chain, we have (from Chapman-Kolmogorov)
   $$p^n_{x,A^c} = \sum_{i_1, \dots, i_{n-1} \in S}{p_{x,i_1} \cdots p_{i_{n-1},A^c} }$$
3. Since $A^c \subset S$,
   $$p_{x,A^c}\underbrace{p_{A^c,A^c} \cdots p_{A^c,A^c} }_{n-1 \text{ times}} \le \sum_{i_1, \dots, i_{n-1} \in S}{p_{x,i_1} \cdots p_{i_{n-1},A^c} } = p^n_{x,A^c}$$
4. Similarly,
   $$\underbrace{p_{A^c,A^c} \cdots p_{A^c,A^c} }_{n \text{ times}} \le \sum_{i_1, \dots, i_{n-1} \in S}{p_{A^c,i_1} \cdots p_{i_{n-1},A^c} } = p^n_{A^c,A^c} $$
5. It's easy to see, that
   $$p^n_{A^c,A^c} = 1 - p^n_{A^c,A^c}$$
6. For $x \in A^c$,
   $$p^n_{A^c,A} \ge p^n_{x,A}$$
7. And finally,
   $$p^n_{x,A^c} = 1 - p^n_{x,A} \le 1 - \alpha$$

Using some properties about Markov Chains and all these information, it follows that

$$\begin{aligned}\mathbb P_x(\tau_A > kn) &= \mathbb P (X_0 \not \in A,X_1 \not \in A, \dots, X_n \not \in A, X_{n+1} \not \in A, \dots, X_{2n} \not \in A,\dots, X_{kn - 1} \not \in A,X_{kn} \not \in A\mid X_0 = x)\\
&=\mathbb P(X_0 = x, X_1 \not \in A, \dots, X_n \not \in A, \dots, X_{2n} \not \in A,\dots, X_{kn} \not \in A )\\
&= \lambda_x p_{x,A^c}\underbrace{p_{A^c,A^c}\cdots p_{A^c,A^c}}_{n-1 \text{ times}}\underbrace{\underbrace{p_{A^c,A^c}\cdots p_{A^c,A^c}}_{n \text{ times}}\cdots \underbrace{p_{A^c,A^c}\cdots p_{A^c,A^c}}_{n \text{ times}}}_{k - 1 \text{ times}}\\
&\le p_{x,A^c}\underbrace{p_{A^c,A^c}\cdots p_{A^c,A^c}}_{n-1 \text{ times}}\underbrace{\underbrace{p_{A^c,A^c}\cdots p_{A^c,A^c}}_{n \text{ times}}\cdots \underbrace{p_{A^c,A^c}\cdots p_{A^c,A^c}}_{n \text{ times}}}_{k - 1 \text{ times}} \text{ (from 1)}\\
&\le \left(\sum_{i_1,\dots, i_{n-1} \in S}{p_{x,i_1}p_{i_1,i_2}\cdots p_{i_{n-1},A^c}}\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{i_1,\dots, i_{n-1} \in S}{p_{A^c,i_1}p_{i_1,i_2}\cdots p_{i_{n-1},A^c}}\right)^{k-1} \text{ (from 3 and 4)}\\
&= \left(p^n_{x,A^c}\right)\left(p^n_{A^c,A^c}\right)^{k-1} \text{ (from 2 and 4)}\\
&\le \left(p^n_{x,A^c}\right)\left(1 - p^n_{x,A}\right)^{k-1} \text{ (from 5 and 6)}\\
&\le (1-\alpha)^k \text{ ( from 7)}\end{aligned}$$

This is how I tried to solve item i). Note that,for $i \ge 1$
$$\{\tau_A > i + 1\} \subseteq \{\tau_A > i\}$$
It means that
$$\mathbb P_x(\tau_A = \infty) = \mathbb P_x(\lim_{k \to \infty}{\tau_A > kn}) = \lim_{k \to \infty} {\mathbb P_x({\tau_A > kn})} \le \lim_{k \to \infty}{(1-\alpha)^k} = 0$$
It implies that,
$$\mathbb P_x(\tau_A < \infty) = 1 - \mathbb P_x(\tau_A = \infty) = 1$$

Finally,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}_x[\tau_A] &= \frac{n}{n}\mathbb E_x[\tau_A]\\
&= n\mathbb E_x\left[\frac{\tau_A}{n}\right]\\
&= n\left(\sum_{i \ge 1}{\mathbb P_x\left(\frac{\tau_A}{n} > i\right)}\right)\\
&= n\left(\sum_{i \ge 1}{\mathbb P_x(\tau_A > ni)}\right)\\
&\le n\left(\sum_{i \ge 1}{\mathbb (1-\alpha)^i}\right)\\
&=n \cdot \frac{1}{1 - (1-\alpha)} = \frac{n}{\alpha}
\end{aligned}
$$
Please, help me to find any mistakes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is not clear what $i$ is in the inequality $p_{ii}^n \geq \alpha$, and how $i$ relates to $x$.  I also observe that $\tau_A \leq \infty$ is an inequality that is always true, so its probability is trivially 1.

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake when I wrote $p^n_{ii}$. The correct is $p^n_{x,A}$.

Comment: I’m sure you mean $E[\tau_A]\leq n/\alpha$ since you cannot infer equality from the given information. To prove (i) you group the $kn$ slots into groups of $n$ consecutive slots. You get (ii) from (i) using a sum formula for expectation of nonnegative integer random variables.

Comment: But, do you know how to get this $(1 - \alpha)^k$ formula? I tried to show by induction, but I think I'm missing some property about the $\tau_A > kn$ probability. Is there some trick or theorem to help me?

Comment: You group the $kn$ slots into groups of $n$ consecutive.  Every $n$ consecutive slots you independently enter $A$.

Comment: Ok! I gonna try, and after that, I will come back here to see if I'm in the right direction.

Comment: I tried to use the sum formula for expectation of nonnegative integer random variables
$$\mathbb{E}[T] = \sum_{i \ge 0}{\mathbb{P}(T > i)}$$
but, I can't get a '$\le$' innequalty.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $x\in A$ then $\tau_A=0$ and so $$0=\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A>kn)\leq (1-\alpha)^k$$ On the other hand, if $x\notin A$ we can say that $$\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A>kn)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\notin A,X_2 \notin A,\ldots,X_{kn}\notin A|X_0=x)$$ The right hand side is bounded above by $$\mathbb{P}(X_n\notin A,X_{2n}\notin A,\ldots,X_{kn}\notin A|X_0=x)$$ Using the chain rule for conditional probability along with Markov this equals $$\mathbb{P}(X_n\notin A|X_0=x)\times \mathbb{P}(X_{2n}\notin A|X_n\notin A)\times \dots \times\mathbb{P}(X_{kn}\notin A|X_{(k-1)n}\notin A)$$ which is bounded above by $(1-\alpha)^k$. Clearly if $x\in A$ then $\mathbb{E}_x(\tau_A)=0$ so for $x \notin A$ we have that $$\mathbb{E}_x(\tau_A)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A > j)=1+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A>j)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=kn}^{kn+n-1}\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A>j)$$ Because $$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A>j)\leq(n-1)\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A>1)\leq(n-1)(1-\alpha)$$ $$\sum_{j=kn}^{kn+n-1}\mathbb{P_x}(\tau_A>j)\leq n\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A>kn)\leq n(1-\alpha)^k$$ it follows that $$\mathbb{E}_x(\tau_A)\leq1+(n-1)(1-\alpha)+n\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-\alpha)^k=\alpha(1-n)+\frac{n}{\alpha}\leq \frac{n}{\alpha}$$ as desired. Now we'll prove $\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A<\infty)=1$ for $x\notin A$. For $j\geq n$ we have $$\mathbb{P}(X_j\notin A,\ldots ,X_1 \notin A|X_0=x)\leq \mathbb{P}(X_{n\left \lfloor{j/n}\right \rfloor }\notin A,\ldots,X_n \notin A|X_0=x)$$ The right hand side is bounded above by $(1-\alpha)^{\left \lfloor{j/n}\right \rfloor }$ and finally $$\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A=\infty)\leq \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}(1-\alpha)^{\left \lfloor{j/n}\right \rfloor}=0 $$

Comment: Hi, Matthew! Can you see if my answer is right?

Comment: Let me take a look. Please fact check my answer too. Note when I say "using the Markov property" I'm first using the chain rule of conditional probability $$P(A_1\cap A_2 \cap A_3|A_0)=P(A_3| A_0\cap A_1 \cap A_2)P(A_2|A_0\cap A_1)P(A_1|A_0)$$ and then applying the Markov property.

Comment: I think you can simplify you first argument by noting that $$\{X_1\notin A\}\cap \ldots \cap \{X_{kn}\notin A\}\subseteq\{X_n\notin A\}\cap \ldots \cap \{X_{kn}\notin A\}$$ Also, it may not be necessry to define an initial distribution $\lambda_x$ on $X_0$.

Comment: Lastly, you argument that $\mathbb{P}_x(\tau_A=\infty)=0$ looks better than mine :)